# spark term frequency transformation

Tags: apache-spark, machine-learning, apache-spark-mllib, tf-idf

I have a set of words in a sentence which I have tokenized and applied Term Frequency Transformation.

```
int numFeatures = 9000;
    hashingTF = new HashingTF().setInputCol("filtered").setOutputCol("features")
            .setNumFeatures(numFeatures);
    DataFrame rawFeaturizedData = hashingTF.transform(stopWordsRemoved);
    rawFeaturizedData.show();
```

When I print the data frame , I see values like below for the "features" column

```
(9000,[2010,2113,2599,3807,5109,5849],[1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0])
```

9000 is the number of features configured for term frequency computation. I have set this to 9000 since there were 8000 unique words after applying text transformations ( stop word removal , lemmetization etc )

[2010,2113,2599,3807,5109,5849]  - I assume these are the numbers assigned to each word in the text ( features )

what is [1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0] ? - By definition , term frequency does hashing of words and also compute the weightage of each word . Is this the weightage ? Why does it always show as 1.0 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following:

```
(9000,[2010,2113,2599,3807,5109,5849],[1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0])
```

is a Spark string representation of the `SparseVector` where:

- Leading number is a size of the vector (here number of features).
- The first array is a list of non-zero indices.
- The second array is a list of values (here weights).

Indices are equal to one if:

- There are no duplicate tokens.
- There are no hashing conflicts.

Let's say input data looks like this:

```scala
val df = Seq("orange orange apple", "apple orange kiwi").toDF("text")
  .withColumn("filtered", split($"text", "\\s+"))
```

If we use 11 features:

```scala
val hashingTF11 = new HashingTF()
  .setInputCol("filtered")
  .setOutputCol("features")
  .setNumFeatures(11)
```

and transform:

```scala
hashingTF11.transform(df).show(2, false)
```

we'll see `2.0` for the first row (orange is represented twice):

```
+-------------------+-----------------------+---------------------------+
|text               |filtered               |features                   |
+-------------------+-----------------------+---------------------------+
|orange orange apple|[orange, orange, apple]|(11,[9,10],[2.0,1.0])      |
|apple orange kiwi  |[apple, orange, kiwi]  |(11,[6,9,10],[1.0,1.0,1.0])|
+-------------------+-----------------------+---------------------------+
```

but if we reduce number of features to 10:

```scala
val hashingTF10 = new HashingTF()
  .setInputCol("filtered")
  .setOutputCol("features")
  .setNumFeatures(10)
```

and transform:

```scala
hashingTF10.transform(df).show(2, false)
```

both rows will have features with weight 2.0:

```
+-------------------+-----------------------+--------------------+
|text               |filtered               |features            |
+-------------------+-----------------------+--------------------+
|orange orange apple|[orange, orange, apple]|(10,[1,3],[1.0,2.0])|
|apple orange kiwi  |[apple, orange, kiwi]  |(10,[1,3],[2.0,1.0])|
+-------------------+-----------------------+--------------------+
```

due to hash collision.